# Using REGISTRY KEY to find installed program

Tags: batch

I use below batch to check if Adobe Reader is installed. When running, it shows the REGISTRY KEY details of the installed program. How possible not to show the REGKEY details ?

```
REM Check file existence in REGISTRY KEY
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe" /ve
if not errorlevel 1 (
echo Adobe Reader already installed
ping /n 6 localhost>nul 2>&1
) else (
echo Install Adobe Reader now
pause
Call "%~dp0..\Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Use PowerShell instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid seeing the output, modify the `reg query` command so as to
redirect all output to `nul`, like this :

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe" /ve >nul 2>&1
```

To avoid all output of all the other command, add at the beginning
of the scrip this
[echo command](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html):

```
@echo off
```